# How to prevent f.write to output the number of characters written?

Tags: python-3.x

I use Python3 and write result into a file like this:

```
with open(output,'w') as f:
    f.write('Line count of the log files is: ' + str(line_count) + '. \n')
```

`f.write()` automatically returns # of characters written, is there a way to do not output it? I ask this because I do not want it output.

Thanks.

Comment: In a script, the `f.write` return value won't get autoprinted, so you don't need to worry about it. If you need to suppress the output in interactive mode, you can assign the return value to a dummy variable.

Comment: `_ = f.write(...)` as the previous comment suggested.

Answer (score 20):

This is not unique to `file.write()`.  The interactive interpreter prints the result of any evaluated expression that does not result in `None`.

```
>>> for i in range(3):
...     i # expression evaluates to the value of i
...
0
1
2
>>>
```

Two things to note.  First, these won't be displayed when you are not using the interactive interpreter, so it's safe to ignore.

Second, you can make the display go away by assigning the result.  That turns the expression into a statement.

```
>>> for i in range(3):
...     _ = i  # underscore is a nice meaningless variable name
...
>>>
```

Comment: I run Python3 in MacOS, the expression "file.write()" does return a value because I use the interactive interpreter, what is it? If I do not use it, the display is gone, yes, if I run the script in Shell using the command line, the value is not printed. However, I still do not know why.

Comment: As explained in the answer, you simply need to assign the return value to a variable.  For example, update to `a = file.write()` or, to show you don't care about the return value, `_ = file.write()`.