# number printed to console when writing to file

Tags: python

I am using this code to write a dictionary to the file system as tab separated file:

```
with open("C:/bla/bla.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for key, value in some_dictionary.items():
        f.write("%s\t%s\n" % (key, value))
```

not only does it crash my IDE (in this case Visual Studio) but it also writes stuff to the console. Not sure why? IMHO the code above is OK and should simply write to the file system. Thanks!

Comment: `f.write(string)` writes the contents of string to the file, **returning the number of characters written**

Comment: ok thanks - how can I suppress this please? Thanks!

Comment: Are you running this in an interactive shell? Only then should that output appear. Also, what is the actual problem here? Crashing the IDE or writing some numbers to the console?

Comment: which python version you are using?

Comment: 3.6 thanks. sorry about my ignorance - just a python newbie

Comment: @tobias_k - i think the writing to console is the problem. there are about 79000+ keays in the dictionary ..

Comment: did some google: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41149781/how-to-prevent-f-write-to-output-the-number-of-characters-written

Comment: The result of the function will only be echoed if you run this in an interactive shell. Just copy those three lines to a `.py` file and run that. Or assign the result to some variable to suppress the echoing: `_ = f.write(...)`

Comment: yes thanks - I learned this in the meantime. sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent f.write to output the number of characters written?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41149781/how-to-prevent-f-write-to-output-the-number-of-characters-written)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
with open("C:/bla/bla.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for key, value in some_dictionary.items():
        a = f.write("%s\t%s\n" % (key, value))
```

You can assign the result like this to avoid printing console, as said in: [How to prevent f.write to output the number of characters written?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41149781/how-to-prevent-f-write-to-output-the-number-of-characters-written)